# "I'm better at X than you are at Y" or "I love X more than I miss Y"

Tags: grammar

**Preface:** If "I'm better at X than you are at Y" or "I love X more than I miss Y" don't use the same construct, please advise and I will edit this post to ask only one question or the other. I've included both under the assumption that they are related and thus may use a similar grammatical construction.

**Question:** When expressing two **disjunctive** ideas that may or may not be attributable to the same person and that are not of the same metric, what is the correct grammatical construct to use?

**Examples of what I'm asking:**

**1)** I'm better at **playing basketball** than John is at **singing karaoke**. (different parties (i.e., **me versus you**), different metrics (i.e., **playing versus singing**))

**2)** I **love Japan** more than I **miss America** (so I'll stay in Japan). (same party (i.e., **me**), different metrics (i.e., **love versus miss**))

**Background:** I've been unable to find such a construct in either A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar, A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar, or on Google. For whatever reason, I'm reminded of the two possible ways of expressing "while" (ながら when referring to the same person and 間/間に when referring to two different parties). I imagine that there exists a concise way of expressing something similar in the case of my question.

**My attempt at an answer:**

**1)** I'm better at playing basketball than John is at singing karaoke.

> ジョンがカラオケを歌うのより僕はバスケ**が**得意です。/ジョンがカラオケを歌うのより僕はバスケをやる**の方が**得意です。

**2)** I love Japan more than I miss America.

> (僕は)アメリカが恋しいより日本**が**好きです。/(僕は)アメリカが恋しいより日本**の方が**好きです。

Answer (score 5):

I would probably say...

> 1. ジョンのカラオケより、僕のバスケのほうがうまい。
> 2. アメリカは恋しいけど、(それよりも)日本のほうが好きだ。
>    or アメリカには帰りたいけど、それよりも日本にいたい(気持ちのほうが強い)。

cf.

> 「私の英語より君の日本語のほうがうまいから、日本語でしゃべろう。」
> "You're better at speaking Japanese than I am at speaking English, so let's speak Japanese."

> 「私の英作文能力より君の日本語読解力のほうが上だから、日本語で書くよ。」
> "You're better at reading Japanese than I am at writing English, so I'll write in Japanese."